# Pass data from Modal to Laravel Controller@update

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-5.3, bootstrap-modal

I need to update some columns from my DB using the modal... question is how do I pass the data from the Modal to the Controller@update? I can get dynamic data to the Modal, but the form action does not appear to function. Can someone help me? I'm getting really frustrated by this.

=( here is my code, that is generating the modal according:

//route

```
Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController');
```

//DashboardController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $equipments = Equipments::all();
        $serviceProviders = ServiceProviders::all();
        $engineers = Engineers::all();
        $equipmentsDue = Equipments::Where('due1', '<>', '1990-01-01')
                                ->orderBy($due1)
                                ->get();
        $customerSite = CustomerSites::all();
        return view('dashboard.index', compact('sort', 'customerSite', 'equipmentsDue', 'serviceProviders', 'engineers'));
    }
```

// /dashboard/index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($equipmentsDue as $equipment)
    <!------modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{ $equipment->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Next Due</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="app-form" id="modal-form" action="/dashboard/update/{{ $equipment->id }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Next Due*</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" name="due1" placeholder="Next Due">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Completed By:</label>
                            <!-- Service Provider -->
                            <select name="note1" class="form-control" id="note1">
                                @foreach ($serviceProviders as $serviceProvider)
                                    <option value="{{ $serviceProvider->id }}">{{ $serviceProvider->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Engineer -->
                            <label for="title">Engineer</label>
                            <select name="note2" class="form-control" id="note2">
                                @foreach ($engineers as $engineer)
                                    <option value="{{ $engineer->id }}">{{ $engineer->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
                            <label for="title">Comments:</label>
                            <textarea name="note3" class="form-control" id="note3" placeholder="comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- modal ends-->  
    <tr class="alert-danger">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td align="center">{{ date("d-m-Y", strtotime($equipement->due1)) }}</td>
        <td align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">TMU</button></td>
        <td>{{ $equipment->CustomerSites->customer->name . " -> " . $equipment->CustomerSites->sitename }}</td>
        <td>{{ $equipment->CustomerSites->SiteRegions->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $equipment->sn  }}</td>
        <td>{{ $equipment->cap  }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{ $equipment->id}}">COMPLETE</button></td>
    </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This correctly generates the table and the modal:

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqfsM.png)

The URL for the

Why the Form action dashboard@update does not call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `update` is actually a `PUT` call and since `form` can't do a proper `PUT` call towards `Laravel Controller` you need to do [`form method spoofing`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) and use the code below:

```
<form class="app-form" id="modal-form" action="{{ route('dashboard', $equipment->id) }}" method="POST">
     {{ method_field('PUT') }}
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add a different rout:
`Route::POST('/dashboard/update/{id}', 'DashboardController@update');`

Controller:

`public function update(Request $request, $id) {
   $the_id = $id; //this is the id.
   dd($id); //to check your id value.
}`

and also try to dd() your variables/ outputs for testing . . .